# Why does groupby().agg(list_funcs) function in Pandas takes significantly more time with a list of functions, than using them individually?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Consider the following code for any dataframe **df** and any random set of cols ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']:

```
df.groupby('A')['B', 'C', 'D'].agg(['mean', 'std', 'count'])
```

here all the aggregation functions are passed together as a **list**.

This takes significantly more time than:

```
grpd = df.groupby('A')['B', 'C', 'D']
grpd.agg('mean')
grpd.agg('std')
grpd.agg('count')
```

where each aggregation function is being **called separately**.

This seems counter intuitive, as I expected Pandas to do something under the hood to make it faster.

Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think reason is pandas use [cython optimalized code](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/user_guide/groupby.html#cython-optimized-aggregation-functions) if called separately, for test added `concat` for same outputs:

```
np.random.seed(123)
N = 1000000
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1000, size=(N, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
print (df)

In [176]: %%timeit
     ...: df.groupby('A')['B', 'C', 'D'].agg(['mean', 'std', 'count'])
     ...: 
274 ms ± 7.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [177]: %%timeit
     ...: grpd = df.groupby('A')['B', 'C', 'D']
     ...: a = grpd.agg('mean')
     ...: b = grpd.agg('std')
     ...: c = grpd.agg('count')
     ...: pd.concat([a,b,c], axis=1)
     ...: 
     ...: 
190 ms ± 980 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [178]: %%timeit
     ...: grpd = df.groupby('A')['B', 'C', 'D']
     ...: a = grpd.mean()
     ...: b = grpd.std()
     ...: c = grpd.count()
     ...: pd.concat([a,b,c], axis=1)
     ...: 
     ...: 
191 ms ± 4.33 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```